# CDK An ApiMapping key may contain only letters, numbers and one of... error

Tags: python, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I am trying to create an API Gateway mapping with a slash, but the CDK is giving me a formatting error:

`Error: An ApiMapping key may contain only letters, numbers and one of $-_.+!*'(),`

The code I am using:

```
        apigatewayv2.ApiMapping(self, "AccountsGetBasePathMapping",
            api=accounts_get_api,
            domain_name=apigateway.DomainName.from_domain_name_attributes(self, "ApiMyDomainComApiGwCustomDomain",
                domain_name="api.mydomain.com",
                domain_name_alias_hosted_zone_id="xxxx",
                domain_name_alias_target="xxxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com."
            ),
            api_mapping_key="accounts/get",
            stage=accounts_get_api_stage,        
        )
```

However, if I try the same in the console the slash character is allowed:

[image]

Is this a limitation of the AWS CDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`api_mapping_key` means:

The path where this stage should be mapped to on custom domain

This is optional so it does not api_context_path as you put above `accounts/get`

For example: there are some APIs you want to separate, you can define:

On custom domain, you define `api.mydomain.com/apiv1` so `api_mapping_key` in this case is `apiv1`,  `acount` path should be: `api.mydomain.com/apiv1/account`

Comment: If I want all my APIs to be available at / under the custom domain does this mean I don't need the api_mapping at all?